# Deadlock occuring in Clustered Columnstore index

Tags: sql-server, transactions, deadlock, clustered-index, columnstore

We are using clustered columnstore index in our transaction table holding  order fulfillments. This table is regularly updated by different sessions. But, every session is specific to order job number and so, they are not trying to update same row at the same time. But, we are facing deadlock issues due to below scenarios between sessions.

- Row group locking & Page lock
- Row group locking & Row group locking

This is not specific to a stored procedure. It is due to multiple stored procedures updating this table, sequentially one by one, as part of order fulfillment.

The sample schema of the table is very simple:

```
CREATE TABLE OrderFulfillments
(
    OrderJobNumber           INT NOT NULL,
    FulfilledIndividualID    BIGINT NOT NULL,
    IsIndividualSuppressed   BIT NOT NULL,
    SuppressionReason        VARCHAR(100) NULL
)
```

I have given sample deadlock graph for your reference. Please let me know, what approach can I take to avoid this deadlock situation. We need clustered Columnstore index in this table, as we are doing aggregation operations to see how many times an Individual been fulfilled already. without columnstore index, it might be slower.

[image]

Comment: You need to ask yourself what queries are causing the blocking. If the updates were truly sequential then the answer is not the updates but rather other processes like select statements on said table. Find out what the last_wait_type is from sys.DM_exec_requests

Comment: And yes a select statement does still uses some level of locking.

Comment: Thanks clifton. I have applied NOLOCK on every select query. Only for UPDATE, we are not having NOLOCK to avoid data corruption. So, Select is the not the problem here. It is lock escalation to Rowgroup level causing the deadlock. I will update you with wait types information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, the deadlock scenario was due to lock escalations happening, as some of the fulfillments were very big and in 10,000s or in 100k ranges and it was causing lock escalation to happen to rowgroup level and in some cases, page level.

I solved this issue by having a temporary table at the very beginning of transactions and work on updates on the temporary table and finally inserting the temporary table related fulfillments information in to this `OrderFulfillments`. This `OrderFulfillments` is also being used by temporary table to see how many times the individual is already fulfilled. but, it is shared lock on the top and not exclusive locks.

By going for temporary table, every session is working on their own copy and concurrency issues are resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You assume NOLOCK is the same as no locking...that is incorrect.

**NOLOCK Is equivalent to READUNCOMMITTED.**

> • READUNCOMMITTED and NOLOCK hints apply only to data locks.
>
> All queries, including those with READUNCOMMITTED and NOLOCK hints,
>   **acquire Sch-S (schema stability) locks during compilation and
>    execution**. Because of this, queries are blocked when a concurrent
>   transaction holds a Sch-M (schema modification) lock on the table.
>
> For example, a data definition language (DDL) operation acquires a Sch-M
>   lock before it modifies the schema information of the table.
>
> Any concurrent queries, including those running with READUNCOMMITTED or
>   NOLOCK hints, are blocked when attempting to acquire a Sch-S lock.
>   **Conversely, a query holding a Sch-S lock blocks a concurrent
>   transaction that attempts to acquire a Sch-M lock.**
>
> READUNCOMMITTED and NOLOCK cannot be specified for tables modified by
>   insert, update, or delete operations. The SQL Server query optimizer
>   ignores the READUNCOMMITTED and NOLOCK hints in the FROM clause that
>   apply to the target table of an UPDATE or DELETE statement.
>
> *You can minimize locking contention while protecting transactions from
>   dirty reads of uncommitted data modifications by using either of the
>   following:*
>
> •  The READ COMMITTED isolation level with the
>   READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT database option set ON.
>
> •  The SNAPSHOT
>   isolation level. For more information about isolation levels, see SET
>   TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL (Transact-SQL).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table

- Understand how your Indexes are structured can cause blocking if say, a select statement requires an entire page that your UPDATE is modifying concurrently.
- Limit your variables upon testing.
- Consider splitting your DML into sections. You may find an optimal range for performing concurrent modifications of your table data.

Comment: and stop using NOLOCK so profusely. The optimizer is generally smart enough and if you use NOLOCK a lot, consider a different ISOLATION strategy.